# Proguard with Cordova Android 4?

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, proguard, cordova-plugin-proguard

I had ProGuard running for release builds when Cordova built with Ant, but now that Gradle is used my project's release builds aren't being obfuscated (my "cordova build --release android" output shows a step for :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles, but no other proguard/minification/obfuscation entries).

With Ant, my project.properties file referred to my proguard-project.txt file using the proguard.config parameter.

How do I configure this to work now that Cordova uses Gradle?

Comment: you can use cordova-plugin-proguard https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-setup-proguard-in-cordova-application/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the updated [Proguard Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#enabling-gradle), you now have to change the `build.gradle` file.

Change the buildType release section to something like this

```
android {
...

  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but Cordova-Android's build.gradle file has this comment:  
  
**// GENERATED FILE! DO NOT EDIT!**  
  
I'm looking for a solution that's compatible with Cordova

Comment: Well that is just the normal behaviour. This get's only overwritten, when you re-initialize the project. It is an android specific that has nothing to do with cordova - you could also assign a hook that reenables that automatically after you add the android platform if you want to be safe.

Comment: The file proguard-rules.pro is an Android Studio artifact; using proguard-project.txt instead did the trick - this is what it was called in an earlier Cordova release. As another comment suggested, I'm adding these properties in an after_platform_add hook.

Comment: you can use cordova-plugin-proguard https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-setup-proguard-in-cordova-application/